# Select last changed row in sub-query

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table **product**:

```
id | owner_id | last_activity | box_id
------------------------------------
1  |     2    | 12/19/2014    | null
2  |     2    | 12/13/2014    | null
3  |     2    | 08/11/2014    | null
4  |     2    | 12/11/2014    | 99
5  |     2    | null          | 99
6  |     2    | 12/15/2014    | 99
7  |     2    | null          | 105
8  |     2    | null          | 105
9  |     2    | null          | 105
```

The only variable that I have is **owner_id**. 
I need to select all products of a user, but if the product is in a box then only latest one should be selected.

Sample output for owner = 2 is following:

```
id | owner_id | last_activity | box_id
------------------------------------
1  |     2    | 12/19/2014    | null
2  |     2    | 12/13/2014    | null
3  |     2    | 08/11/2014    | null
6  |     2    | 12/15/2014    | 99
7  |     2    | null          | 105
```

I'm not able to find a way to select the latest product from a box.

My current query, which does not return correct value, but can be executed:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
WHERE p.owner_id = 2
AND (
  p.box IS NULL
  OR (
    p.box IS NOT NULL
    AND
    p.id = ( SELECT MAX(pp.id) FROM product pp
             WHERE pp.box_id = p.box_id )
  )
```

I tried with dates:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
WHERE p.owner_id = 2
AND (
  p.box IS NULL
  OR (
    p.box IS NOT NULL
    AND
    p.id = ( SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT pp.id FROM product pp
              WHERE pp.box_id = p.box_id 
              ORDER BY last_activity desc
            ) WHERE rownum = 1
           )
  )
```

Which gives error: **p.box_id** is undefined as it's inside 2nd subquery.

Do you have any ideas how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the _"latest"_ ? In particular, you have `NULL` values in the `last_activity` column -- how are they taken into account.

Comment: Yes, there can be nulls as a value. If there are nulls in all products inside a box, then MIN(id) should be returned.

Comment: It is probably **not** a good idea to rely on `id` to order things. Assuming you populate that column from a sequence, think about concurrent access: a "pool" of `id` might have been reserved by a client, but not used immediatly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytical function might help with such queries:

```
SELECT  "owner_id", "id", "box_id", "last_activity" FROM
(

    SELECT "owner_id", "id", "box_id", "last_activity",
           ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY "box_id" ORDER BY "last_activity" DESC NULLS LAST) rn
            --                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            --               descending order, reject nulls after not null values
            --                                 (this is the default, but making it
            --                                  explicit here for self-documentation
            --                                  purpose)
    FROM T
    WHERE "owner_id" = 2

) V
WHERE rn = 1 or "box_id" IS NULL
ORDER BY "id" -- <-- probably not necessary, but matches your example
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db775/8

---

> there can be nulls as a value. If there are nulls in all products inside a box, then MIN(id) should be returned

Even if is is probably **not** a good idea to rely on `id` to order things is you think you need that, you will have to change the `ORDER BY` clause to:

```
... ORDER BY "last_activity" DESC NULLS LAST, "id" DESC
--                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes! `ROW_NUMBER` does the trick. Thank you! I think here I can rely on the id, because system that I work on inserts products in given order, so if `last_activity` is null, I can simply use `id` and can be sure about result.

Answer (score 0):

Use exists

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM
  product p
WHERE
  p.owner_id = 2 AND
  ( p.box IS NULL OR
    (
      p.box IS NOT NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS
      (
        SELECT
          pp.id
        FROM
          product pp
        WHERE
          pp.box_id = p.box_id AND
          pp.last_activity > p.last_activity
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to first get all rows where box_is null and than fetch rows with max id and date where box_id is not null:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT id,owner_id,last_activity,box_id FROM product WHERE owner_id = 2 AND box_id IS NULL
   UNION
   SELECT MAX(id),owner_id,MAX(last_activity),box_id FROM product WHERE owner_id = 2 AND box_id IS NOT    NULL GROUP BY owner_id, box_id 
) T1
ORDER BY
    id
```